# Copy shopify products, customers and orders using api

Tags: shopify

I have to clone shopify products, customers and orders from one store to another using API. I am able to do this successfully for products and customers. For creating relationship between source and destinatio store products I have used handlers.

Customers are linked based on customer email.

But order feed has customer and product Id of source store. My new store has own product Id and i don't know how to relate new products. Also I need to check if this order has been imported or not. I am not able to find anything with which I can work.
Because token, cart token, checkout token and order number changed for each store. Can someone help me in resolving this.

Thanks

Comment: Simple answer you can't. Try creating new orders with same details as previous. Would help to have id mappings.

Comment: I can create new orders by giving product name. But while importing orders, there are some refunds as well. I need to know product id for which refund needs to generate.

Comment: This seems like something Shopify should support. It is easier to migrate orders to another e-commerce platform than it is to migrate from one Shopify store to another.